# Can someone give some examples of when a perfect graph is not a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone give some examples of when a perfect graph is not a complete graph? I do understand the textbook definition of them but examples would help.

Answer (score 2):

bipartite graphs: Any induced subgraph is colorable by 1 or 2 colors, and any maximal clique has size 1 or 2, depending whether your vertex subset hits only one part of the partition or both.

interval graphs: induced subgraphs are again interval graphs, and both the size of a maximal clique and the chromatic number are given by the maximal number of intervals that have a common intersection.

There are more.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest example of a perfect graphs which is not a clique is a $P_3$ (i.e. a path on 3 vertices with two edges, which is also the smallest graph which is not a clique).

Further, every acyclic graph (i.e. a tree or a disjoint collection of trees) is perfect.